# Matroska format's framerate is not accurate with certain values

Tags: ffmpeg, framerate, screen-casting, matroska

If the Matroska format is used, in certain framerates it doesn't record at exact input framerate, but rather at a little higher than the input framerate.

As an example:

```
ffmpeg -video_size 1920x1080 -f x11grab -framerate 30 -i :0.0 -c:v libx264rgb -crf 0 -preset ultrafast video.mkv
```

doesn't generate a recording at 30fps, but rather at 30.0003fps.

This is not good, because even a slight change in input framerate can cause major frame stutter. Unless ffmpeg is speeding up the stream by 1.00001x, which I don't think so when using x11grab.

To prove this, VLC can be used for checking the frame rate.

Is there any way to force exactly 30fps, or is this a format flaw?

Also, `uname -a`:

```
Linux linux 4.1.15-rt17-1-rt-fixedtimers #1 SMP PREEMPT RT Sat Jan 16 01:14:52 GMT+5 2016 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: How does "major frame stutter" manifest itself? I can imagine sync issues but I can't quite picture how anything major could come from a 1 part per 10000 rate error.

Comment: Please show the complete console output from your `ffmpeg` command.

Comment: I just noticed this only happens on .mkv format. I'm updating information about this. Here's the paste: http://pastebin.com/yUbn1zrL

Comment: For recording to MKV, insert `-vsync 0`. Whatever rate the source supplies, MKV will encode the same timings.

Answer (score 3):

MKV does not store a frame rate in its container. So ffmpeg/vlc looks at the default duration of a frame instead. It sees 33.333ms and does the math, which is where your weird number comes from.

For more information, see: https://gitlab.com/mbunkus/mkvtoolnix/wikis/Wrong-frame-rate-displayed

To test this out, you can run `ffprobe` with `-show_frames`. I think you'll find the presentation times for each frame are spot on.